# Ubuntu 22.04 ssh-agent identities not added correctly?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, git, ssh-agent

I have my ssh identities added at the end of the .bashrc script, as the server says here when I log in, Agent is running with pid 8411 and all of the identitias are added.

As is also evident from the console below, I can not use my identities. In order to use them, I need to type a command to start the ssh agent (which now receives a new pid 8531) and also type the command to add the identity to the agent (again?), and only then will git recognize the identity and allow to pull the repo.

What is going on here, what am I doing wrong?

```
Last login: Sat Jul  1 11:51:58 2023 from 162.243.190.66
Agent pid 8411
Identity added: /root/.ssh/id_ed25519 (mattias@domain.se)
Identity added: /root/.ssh/id_ed25519_api_requests (mattias@domain.se)
Identity added: /root/.ssh/id_ed25519_airspace_sweden (mattias@domain.se)
Identity added: /root/.ssh/id_ed25519_hwx (mattias@domain.se)
root@DR2-sweden-internal-api:~# cd /var/www/html
root@DR2-sweden-internal-api:/var/www/html# ls
aircraft  airspace  airspace-sweden  drones  index.html
root@DR2-sweden-internal-api:/var/www/html# git clone git@github.com:domain/myrepo-api-out-HemsWX.git
Cloning into 'myrepo-api-out-HemsWX'...
ERROR: Repository not found.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
root@DR2-sweden-internal-api:/var/www/html# eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
Agent pid 8531
root@DR2-sweden-internal-api:/var/www/html# ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_ed25519_hwx
Identity added: /root/.ssh/id_ed25519_hwx (mattias@domain.se)
root@DR2-sweden-internal-api:/var/www/html# git clone git@github.com:domain/myrepo-api-out-HemsWX.git
Cloning into 'myrepo-api-out-HemsWX'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 91, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (91/91), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (65/65), done.
remote: Total 91 (delta 35), reused 79 (delta 23), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (91/91), 20.14 KiB | 2.88 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (35/35), done.
```

This is at the end of my ~/.bashrc

```
#add github deploy keys to agent
eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_ed25519_api_requests
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_ed25519_airspace_sweden
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_ed25519_hwx
```

------- UPDATE (for Ulrichs comment) ----------

So I notice that the first of the four identities is usable. The -v gave a whole lot of debug lines =)

```
debug1: Connecting to github.com [140.82.121.3] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519 type 3  // <------ one of my 4 identity files
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.7
```

Or is that just listing they type of identity files it looks for? Because further down I got this:

```
debug1: Will attempt key: /root/.ssh/id_ed25519 ED25519 SHA256:pHUHZ1LHAiGC0z---------------------- agent
debug1: Will attempt key: mattias@domain.se ED25519 SHA256:6U2cH2OBWTIuVGx---------------------- agent
debug1: Will attempt key: mattias@domain.se ED25519 SHA256:o+a6AiJJzpLFqjV---------------------- agent
debug1: Will attempt key: mattias@domain.se ED25519 SHA256:Yz4Ayq8x/6bqf9D---------------------- agent
debug1: Will attempt key: /root/.ssh/id_rsa 
debug1: Will attempt key: /root/.ssh/id_dsa 
debug1: Will attempt key: /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa 
debug1: Will attempt key: /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk 
debug1: Will attempt key: /root/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk 
debug1: Will attempt key: /root/.ssh/id_xmss
```

So it seems that it attempts keys, but why is there only a path on first one of them? The others have no path but only my email adress?

```
debug1: Will attempt key: /root/.ssh/id_ed25519 ED25519 SHA256:pHUHZ1LHAiGC0z---------------------- agent
debug1: Will attempt key: mattias@domain.se ED25519 SHA256:6U2cH2OBWTIuVGx---------------------- agent
debug1: Will attempt key: mattias@domain.se ED25519 SHA256:o+a6AiJJzpLFqjV---------------------- agent
debug1: Will attempt key: mattias@domain.se ED25519 SHA256:Yz4Ayq8x/6bqf9D---------------------- agent
```

------------ UPDATE (for aviro's comment) ---------

the agent is indeed running with a PID of 165201. However adding the identity manually to that agent is not helping as seen below. Also as seen below, running eval on the agent again, and then manually adding the identity does the trick. I notice that there is only one agent running, so the PID is replaced with a new PID when running eval on the agent.

```
root@DR2-sweden-internal-api:/var/www/html/hwx# echo $SSH_AGENT_PID;
165201
root@DR2-sweden-internal-api:/var/www/html/hwx# ps -fp $SSH_AGENT_PID
UID          PID    PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
root      165201       1  0 08:14 ?        00:00:00 ssh-agent -s
root@DR2-sweden-internal-api:/var/www/html/hwx# ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_ed25519_hwx
Identity added: /root/.ssh/id_ed25519_hwx (mattias@domain.se)
root@DR2-sweden-internal-api:/var/www/html/hwx# git fetch
ERROR: Repository not found.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
root@DR2-sweden-internal-api:/var/www/html/hwx# 


root@DR2-sweden-internal-api:/var/www/html/hwx# eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
Agent pid 166484
root@DR2-sweden-internal-api:/var/www/html/hwx# ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_ed25519_hwx
Identity added: /root/.ssh/id_ed25519_hwx (mattias@domain.se)
root@DR2-sweden-internal-api:/var/www/html/hwx# git fetch
remote: Enumerating objects: 5, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (5/5), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (1/1), done.
remote: Total 3 (delta 2), reused 3 (delta 2), pack-reused 0
Unpacking objects: 100% (3/3), 721 bytes | 721.00 KiB/s, done.
From github.com:Naviation/dronerequest-api-out-HemsWX
   7bdda64..c620151  master      -> origin/master
 * [new branch]      version_1.2 -> origin/version_1.2
root@DR2-sweden-internal-api:/var/www/html/hwx#
```

Comment: Please try a `ssh -vv git@github.com` with the initial agent so we can see more detail.

Comment: In addition to the `-v` flag suggested by @UlrichSchwarz, please also check if your agent is running by running the command: `echo $SSH_AGENT_PID; ps -fp $SSH_AGENT_PID`. If i your agent is running, please try to add the key to the agent in your shell **without** running `eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"` before. This will help understand if the problem is with the agent not running/stopping after `.bashrc`, and in case it is running, if it responds to new `ssh-add` commands.

Comment: "I notice that the first of the four identities is usable" – Because `~/.ssh/id_ed25519` is one of the default pathnames `ssh` itself tries.

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz I added some debug output in my recent Edit.

Comment: @aviro I added some output from your suggestions in the last edit as well.

Comment: 1. For testing purpose, it would be easier to check `ssh git@github.com`. If it works, you should see the message: `You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.` If it fails, you will see `Permission denied (publickey).`. 2. Please compare the output of `ssh git@github.com` between the first and second attempt to confirm my statement. 3. If so, try to compare `ssh -vv git@github.com` between the failed and successful attempt, you might be able to see the difference.

Comment: Also, examine the difference between the failed and successful attempt. In the failed attempt, you add 4 keys. In the successful attempt you add only one. In order to make a true comparison, do the following: 1. After you run `eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"` manually, add all four keys and check just like you do in your `~/.bashrc`. That's way you're comparing apples to apples. I suspect it might fail. 2. In your `~/.bashrc`, only add one key - `~/.ssh/id_ed25519_hwx`, just like you did interactively. Then start a new shell and check if it works.